# RavenDB 4.2 - Auto Generated ID Field

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, ravendb

I am creating a basic API with RavenDB and .NetCore 3.1 MVC. I am using the auto generated ID field which is "Modelnames/123-ClusterInstance". Since my controllers will default to myapi.com/api/ssolinks/{id}, the field will end up being myapi.com/api/ssolinks/**SSOLinks/123-ClusterInstance** (the id). How would you recommend I get around this? I found an old SO post here: [Autogenerated Id in RavenDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590506/autogenerated-id-in-ravendb) but the documentation seems to be gone. I have worked around it by appending it in the HTTP request but it feels hacky. Thanks for any input!

```
namespace myAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SSOLinksController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult Get(string Id)
        {
            //I want to NOT do this if possible :D
            Id = $"SSOLinks/{Id}";
            var store = DocumentStoreHolder.CreateStore();
            using (IDocumentSession session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                List<SSOLink> ssolinks = session
                    .Query<SSOLink>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
                    .ToList();
                return Ok(ssolinks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know you can use _FirstOrDefault()_ instead of _ToList()_ since there is this is a unique document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation seems ok - you get the Id from the URL params and then get it from the RavenDB server.

You can use `startswith`& `matches` in your URL params.
 
See in **Query String Parameters** in [Get Documents By Prefix](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/rest-api/document-commands/get-documents-by-prefix#query-string-parameters)

From the Session you can use [LoadStartingWith](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/session/loading-entities#loadstartingwith)
i.e.

```
 var linkResult = session
         .Advanced
         .LoadStartingWith<SSOLink>("SSOLinks/", <the Id>)
         .FirstOrDefault();
```